# How to disable the number that the Email Registration module puts on peoples username on registration

Tags: 7

I'm working with the email registration module and everywhere I look it says that it just uses everything before the @ sign for the username. However it adds and underscore and some number to every username. I'm not very familiar with php so if someone could tell me to disable this it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out my own problem. The module has a double fail safe for there not being duplicate usernames. Every time a new account is created it adds the uid to the end of the username so that there would be no duplicates, but if there was still a duplicate it will append a 1 or 2 on the end. Since the odds of there being 2 identical usernames from emails I am just commenting out where it adds the uid and going with just the appending a number if it ever does happen. Here is the code I commented out:

```
/* 070715 AS commented this out so the user id is not concatenated to the end of the user name, 
this is just guaranteeing that no 2 people have the same username which has odds so small 
we aren't going to worry about it. 
  if (!empty($uid)) {
    // Put uid on the end of the name.
    $name = $name . '_' . $uid;
  }*/
```

Comment: This may cause issues, drupal expects username to be unique just like email.

Comment: It is still going to be unique because there is a second fail safe for username where if it is the same then it concatenates a 1, 2, 3, or whatever number it is to the end of the username.

Answer (score 0):

I missed that, I remember from your question that you were removing numbers as well. BTW rather hacking this contrib module you can implement a simple hook exposed by this module i.e. [hook_email_registration_name](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/email_registration/email_registration.api.php/function/hook_email_registration_name/7),an example would be

```
function my_modulename_email_registration_name($edit, $account) {
  // Logic to return username, an example would be following.
  return 'u' . $account->uid;
}
```

replace my_modulename with your actual module name.

Comment: can you explain to me that return statement. I don't know php very well so I want to know what that is doing.